# Reduce array of objects without using .push()

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I have this array of objects:

```
[
    {
        user: 'User_1',
        date: 1603926000000,
        count: 3,
    },
    {
        user: 'User_2',
        date: 1603926000000,
        count: 10,
    },
    {
        user: 'User_2',
        date: 1604876400000,
        count: 1,
    },
]
```

I reduce it with this function:

```
const reducedDataByDate = dataByDate.reduce((acc, d) => {
        const foundUser = acc.find((a) => a.user === d.user)
        const value = { date: formatDate(d.date), count: d.count }
        if (!foundUser) {
            acc.push({ user: d.user, data: [value] })
        } else {
            foundUser.data.push(value)
        }
        return acc
    }, [])
```

with this outcome:

```
[
    {
        user: 'User_1',
        data: [
            {
                date: '2020-10-29',
                count: 10,
            },
            {
                date: '2020-11-09',
                count: 1,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        user: 'User_2',
        data: [
            {
                date: '2020-10-29',
                count: 3,
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

Ideally, I would like get rid of pushing values to original `acc` and `foundUser` array but have little idea how to go about that. Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: what do you want instead?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am looking for a way to not mutate the original array. I guess a function collectDataForUser that for a specific user collects all data then add the result of that to acc/ foundUser.

Comment: `foundUser.data[foundUser.data.length] = value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect the data with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get the wanted format from it.

```js
const 
    data = [{ user: 'User_1', date: 1603926000000, count: 3 }, { user: 'User_2', date: 1603926000000, count: 10 }, { user: 'User_2', date: 1604876400000, count: 1 }],
    result = Array.from(
        data.reduce(
            (m, { user, ...o }) => m.set(user, [...(m.get(user) || []), o]),
            new Map
        ),
        ([user, data]) => ({ user, data })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works indeed! However, I don't really understand what's going on here `([user, data]) => ({ user, data })`. Could you clear that up?

Comment: `Array.from` takes an iterable, the map, which is the same as [`Map#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) which returns an array of arrays with key/value pairs and this array is mapped by using the key/`user`and value/`data` as [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for a new object.